# Problems with async / await - How to wait for requests

Tags: javascript, node.js, async-await

I have an array of objects containing metadata for videos. I need to iterate through it and for each object I need to make an API call passing its `filename` to get a `streamingLink` and assign it to the object's `streamingLink`. My problem is by the time I am returning this array, the array is undefined. How do I tell the code to wait until streamingLink has been assigned?

Here's kind of what my code looks like:

```js
// get array from database
const items = await client.db('database').collection('collection').find({}).toArray();

// for each object get and replace streamingLink
let items_withLinks = items.map((item) => {
  getStreamingLink(item.filename) // API call to get link
    .then(response => {
      item.streamingLink = response.result.link;
      return item;
    })
});

console.log(items_withLinks); // undefined
```

I have tried using `await` in different places and wrapping this in an `async` function but I can't figure out the right way to do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The fundamental problem is that the function you are using in the `.map` doesn't return anything. (So you will actually technically get an array of `undefined` values, rather than `undefined` itself - but that obviously is no good.)

You need to `return` the promise and then use `Promise.all` to get the array of results.

```
// get array from database
const items = await client.db('database').collection('collection').find({}).toArray();

// for each object get and replace streamingLink
let items_withLinks = items.map((item) => {
  // return is the only thing I've added here!
  return getStreamingLink(item.filename) // API call to get link
    .then(response => {
      item.streamingLink = response.result.link;
      return item;
    })
});

const result = await Promise.all(items_withLinks);
console.log(result);
```

Comment: Brilliant. Thank you!!

Answer (score 2):

You can loop over your array and create a promise for each item. Then you can call [Promise.all](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all).

```js
const promise1 = Promise.resolve(3);
const promise2 = 42;
const promise3 = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  setTimeout(resolve, 100, 'foo');
});

Promise.all([promise1, promise2, promise3]).then((values) => {
  console.log(values);
});
// expected output: Array [3, 42, "foo"]
```